# converting miles into inches from wolframalpha

Tags: units, wolfram-alpha-queries

I was creating a simple quiz. I noticed that [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert%20.25%20miles%20into%20inches) converts 0.25 miles into 15800 inches while [google converts](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=GdKEVJ-LEtKzuAT8joDYBg#q=convert%20%20.25%20miles%20into%20inches) it into 15840 inches. Is it a bug or did I make some miscalculation?

Comment: If you use `1/4 miles` instead of `.25 miles` you get ``15840` inches in WA.

Comment: @kguler any explanation for weird behaviour?

Comment: Santosh, not sure... Using `.250 miles` also gives the correct result (`WolframAlpha["convert .250 miles to inches", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]`).

Comment: WA knows about significant figures and google does not.  Put 0.2500 into WA and you get improved precision

Comment: Using precision implied by significant figures the "correct" answer is 16000. And how come `.250005` -> 15840` not `15840.3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exact numbers or higher precision numbers gives the result that matches google's output:

```
WolframAlpha["convert 1/4 miles to inches", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
(* 15840 in *)

WolframAlpha["convert .250 miles to inches", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
(* 15840 in *)
```

Another example:

```
WolframAlpha["convert 1/5 miles to inches", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
(* 12672 in *)

WolframAlpha["convert " <> # <> "miles to inches", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}] & /@ 
{".2", ".20", ".200", ".2000"}
(* {12700 in, 12700 in, 12670 in, 12672 in} *)
```